# cpu efficiency formula

Tags: multithreading, cpu

I have a question like this :

Measurement of a certain system have shown that the average process runs for a time T before blocking on IO. A process switch requires a time S, which is effectively wasted ( overhead ). For round robin scheduling with quantum Q, give a formula for the CPU efficiency for each of the following

```
( a ) Q = INFINITY
( b ) Q > T
( c ) S < Q < T
( d ) Q = S
( e ) Q -> 0
```

I know how to do the a,b,d and e, but for c, the answer is T/(T + S * T/Q) = Q/(Q + S). It means the total times context switching occurs is T/Q which makes me confusing, let say T = 3, Q = 2, the process run for 2 units and switch to another process, then later it is switched back to execute and finish, then switch to another process again, so it is 2 switches which is = roof(T/Q); but based on the answer, there is only 1 switching, so there is no different between running in 1 round and 2 rounds? Could anyone explain it to me and what exactly CPU efficiency is.

Comment: I have a same question, could you please give me some references, links from where I can get the description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem doesn't say anything about the scheduler switching when blocked by IO, so I don't the answer you provided is correct. It doesn't take into account the fact that CPU is wasted when the process is blocked by IO. Let's look at an example with 2 processes:

```
repeat floor(T/Q) times:
  Process 1 runs (Q units of time)
  Context switch to process 2 (S units of time)
  Process 2 runs (Q units of time)
  Context switch to process 1 (S units of time)

if T mod Q > 0  
  Process 1 runs (T mod Q units of time) then blocks to IO 
  CPU is idle (Q - T mod Q units of time)
  Context switch to process 2 (S units of time)
  Process 2 runs (T mod Q units of time) then blocks to IO 
  CPU is idle (Q - T mod Q units of time)
  Context switch to process 1 (S units of time)


Total time elapsed = 2(Q+S)*ceiling(T/Q)
Total time processes were running = 2T
Efficiency = T/((Q+S)*ceiling(T/Q))
```

If the scheduler switches once a process is blocked, then:

```
repeat floor(T/Q) times:
  Process 1 runs (Q units of time)
  Context switch to process 2 (S units of time)
  Process 2 runs (Q units of time)
  Context switch to process 1 (S units of time)

if T mod Q > 0  
  Process 1 runs (T mod Q units of time) then blocks to IO 
  Context switch to process 2 (S units of time)
  Process 2 runs (T mod Q units of time) then blocks to IO 
  Context switch to process 1 (S units of time)


Total time elapsed = 2T + 2*S*ceiling(T/Q)
Total time processes were running = 2T
Efficiency = T/(T+S*ceiling(T/Q))
```

So if we assume that the scheduler switches when blocked, the answer you have is just missing the ceiling() part. If we assume that T is always a multiple of Q, then you don't even need it. Not sure what your problem says about that though.

On a side note, I think you were double counting context switches because you were looking at it from the perspective of a single process. The fact that there should be one context switch for every quantum that ran becomes more clear when you consider multiple processes being scheduled.

Comment: when process 1 finished then blocks on IO, i think the CPU will immediately do context switch to process 2 rather than being idle based on the round robin scheduling.

Comment: @skyrel : ok, then the answer looks much closer to what you provided. updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

CPU efficiency is the percentage of time the CPU is doing something useful (i.e. not switching).  Your formula doesn't suggest anything about how many switches are done, just what fraction of the time is being spent NOT switching.

Comment: it said that T/Q is the average time a process spending on switching, so T+S*T/Q is total number of units

Comment: Sorry; I get confused between when you use "time" to mean duration and "time" to mean a count.  I was referring to "based on the answer, there is only 1 switching" -- I don't see where this comes from.  As @pepsi put it, there will be a switch at the end of each quantum hence your computed efficiency.  If this is off due to T not being a multiple of Q, it is because your formula for the time made the same assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I end up getting [(T^2)/(Q)] / [(T^2)/(Q)+(S*((T/Q))-(1/P))]. Using P as the number of processes. Which is the Total time executing divided by the total time (including switches):

Total Executing Time: P[(T/Q) * (T)] , T/Q is how many times each process must run. Then multiply by T again to get the total time processing.

Switching Time: P[((T/Q) * (S)) - S/P] , T/Q * S since we need the total switching times, but now we are counting switch after the last process has finished(an extra count) so we subtract S/P.

Total Time: Executing Time + Switching Time or P[(T^2) / (Q)] + P[((T/Q) * (S)) - (S/P)]

Efficiency: [(T^2)/(Q)] / [(T^2)/(Q)+(S*((T/Q))-(1/P))] Notice the P's drop.

Wolfram Alpha displays properly: [Wolfram Eval](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28T%5E2%29+%2F+Q%29+%2F+%28%28%28T%5E2%29%2FQ%29%2BS%2a%28%28T%2FQ%29+-+%281%2FP%29%29%29)